# moment.calendar() shows "Tomorrow" while expected "Today"

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using `moment.js` to manage my dates in my app. But for some reasons the calendar doesn't always show the expected result, sometimes I'm expecting a `today`value, and i'm finally getting a `tomorrow` one (others values seems right anytimes).

As entry value in my function, I have a timestamp, running inside, moment.now() to get the current day, and finally using the calendar function to compare `current day` and my `timestamp`.

Is this an API issue ? Or maybe new days are calculating after 12 hours ?

// timeStamp = 1506982867000

```
$scope.testDate = function(timeStamp)
{
  // Getting my timeStamp into a moment
  var day = moment(timeStamp);

  // Getting the current day
  var now = moment();

  // moment.Calendar() function
  return day.calendar(now, {
    sameDay: '[Today]',
    nextDay: '[Tomorrow]',
    nextWeek: 'dddd',
    lastDay: 'dddd',
    lastWeek: 'dddd',
    sameElse: 'L'
  });

};
```

## EDIT

Well, when I'm trying to check my date on this website : https://www.epochconverter.com/ I'm getting the right date if GMT, and the wrong one (the one I get in my app), when it's GMT+2.

How can modify this GMT value in my calendar ?

Comment: What's the value of your `timeStamp` variable when you do `console.log(timeStamp)`?

Comment: The `timeStamp` unworking value is : 1506982867000

Comment: I tested it in [**plnkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/tvWSTgpkYDSpSZQ1tHVm?p=preview) and got the correct value of today but I'm in GMT. Seeing your edit, are you saying if someone runs your app in a different timezone you want to change their timezone?

Comment: No, I don't need to change their timezone, because it's designed for only one country for now. But apparently, for some reason the GMT is not right in my app. I've initialized moment like this : `moment.locale('fr');` it should take the right GMT, shouldn't it ? Or is there a moment.calendar() setting somewhere ?

Comment: `moment.locale()` only changes the language as far as I know but doesn't effect timezones. In general when running `moment` on the client it always uses the client's timezone though there is `moment.timezone` which might help https://momentjs.com/timezone/

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by using moment().utcOffset() method. Thanks to Fran for his help !

```js
$scope.testDate = function(timeStamp)
{
  // utcOffset(a) parameter a is for GMT+a
  var day = moment(timeStamp).utcOffset(0);
  var now = moment().utcOffset(0);

  // moment.Calendar() function
  return day.calendar(now, {
    sameDay: '[Today]',
    nextDay: '[Tomorrow]',
    nextWeek: 'dddd',
    lastDay: 'dddd',
    lastWeek: 'dddd',
    sameElse: 'L'
  });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your values to represent UTC, then just initialize your values as UTC:

```
var day = moment.utc(timeStamp);
var now = moment.utc();
```

See also: https://maggiepint.com/2016/05/14/moment-js-shows-the-wrong-date/